Jquery click event doesn't fire on new table row
I am trying to add a new row to the table, and there is a dropdown select in the cell. The click event works for the existing row, however, it doesn't work for the newly added row. Any suggestion?
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">Line No.</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Record Series Number</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Records Series Name</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Temporary BOX#</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Disposal Date</th>

        <th colspan="2" style="text-align:center">Dates of Record</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Range</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Action</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">From</th>
        <th scope="col">To</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr class="rows"><td>1</td ><td><select id="recordsNumber"><option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose here</option><option value="CRA AND LPA CASE FILES">MAG-35-01</option><option value="ROLL NUMBER FILES">MAG 59-01</option><option value="HEARING DOCKETS">MAG 59-02</option></select></td><td><input type='text' id='recordsName' value="test" disabled /></td><td><input type='text' id='tempbox' /></td><td><input type='date' id='disposalDate' /></td><td><input type='date' id='from' /> </td><td><input type='date' id='to' /></td><td><input type='text' id='range' maxlength='200' /></td><td><button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-delete'>Delete</button></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button type="button" id="replicateButton">replicate</button>
</body>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {


$("#mytable tbody tr").on("click", function () {
      var $dropdown = $(this).find('select');
      var selectedText = $dropdown.find('option:selected').text();
      var selectedValue = $dropdown.val();
      $(this).find("input[id='recordsName']").val(selectedValue);
      $(this).find("input[id='recordsName']").prop('title', selectedValue);
      console.log($(this))
  })

    


  $("#replicateButton").on("click", function () {
      debugger;
      var newRow = "<tr><td>1</td><td><select id='recordsNumber'><option value='' selected disabled hidden>Choose here</option><option value='CRA AND LPA CASE FILES'>MAG-35-01</option><option value='ROLL NUMBER FILES'>MAG 59-01</option><option value='HEARING DOCKETS'>MAG 59-02</option></select></td><td><input type='text' id='recordsName' value='test' disabled /></td><td><input type='text' id='tempbox' /></td><td><input type='date' id='disposalDate' /></td><td><input type='date' id='from' /> </td><td><input type='date' id='to' /></td><td><input type='text' id='range' maxlength='200' /></td><td><button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-delete'>Delete</button></td></tr>"
      $("table tbody").append(newRow);
      
  });
});
</script>
</html>

I am trying to add click event to every new row
Sample test

Your current code only adds click listeners to the tr that exist on the page onload, so it doesn't add click event listeners to the trs that don't exist yet. You can get around this by using event delegation by adding a click listener to your parent element and then only firing the event if it matches the a tr:
$("#mytable tbody").on("click", "tr", function () {
  // ...
});

